# How to remove elements of one array from another?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two arrays:

```
A=[1 1 2 2 3 3 3];
B=[1 3];
```

Is there any function that can remove elements which are contained in `B` from `A`?

The result should be

```
C=[1 2 2 3 3];
```

The order is not important, but if there is more specific elements like two times `1` in `A`, then I need operation that removes (from `A`) only as many of these specific elements is in `B` (in this case only one of `1` and one of `3`; meaning other `1` and `3` should remain in final product `C`). This function should be analogous to `setdiff`, with the difference that it should take care of multiple instances of array elements. This analogy can hold because my `B` only contains elements that are in `A`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For loop solution:

```
C = A;    
for ii = 1:length(B)       
   C(find(C == B(ii), 1,'first')) = [];
end
```

Result

```
C =

     1     2     2     3     3
```

Comment: Thanks. I must remember this. But that `A` inside the find must be a `C` or you'll remove the wrong elements. Try it with `A=[1 1 2 2 3 4 4];` for example, if there is an `A` inside the find you end up removing a `4` instead of a `3`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized solution using [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html):

```
maxValue = max([A B]);
counts = accumarray(A(:), 1, [maxValue 1])-accumarray(B(:), 1, [maxValue 1]);
C = repelem(1:maxValue, max(counts, 0));
```

And the result for your sample data `A = [1 1 2 2 3 3 3]; B = [1 3];`:

```
C =

     1     2     2     3     3
```

This will even work for cases where there are values in `B` not in `A` (like `B = [1 4];`) or more of a given value in `B` than in `A` (like `B = [1 1 1];`).

**Note:** The above works since`A` and `B` contain integers. If they were to contain floating-point values, you could map the unique values to integers first using [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html). Let's say we had the following sample data:

```
A = [0 0 pi pi 2*pi 2*pi 2*pi];
B = [0 2*pi];
```

Here's a variant of the above code that can handle this:

```
uniqueValues = unique([A B]);
[~, A] = ismember(A, uniqueValues);
[~, B] = ismember(B, uniqueValues);
maxValue = max([A B]);
counts = accumarray(A(:), 1, [maxValue 1])-accumarray(B(:), 1, [maxValue 1]);
C = uniqueValues(repelem(1:maxValue, max(counts, 0)));
```

And the results:

```
C =

         0    3.1416    3.1416    6.2832    6.2832  % [0 pi pi 2*pi 2*pi]
```